# State updated in Flutter UI not reflected in Firebase Firestore realtime

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

Here I have a stream of objects of which I'm returning from Firestore and being displayed in my UI. My `StreamBuilder` is properly returning the data from my database and is displaying my objects correctly in the UI, however I'm trying to accomplish a two way binding here, when my `PlannerItemContainer` is tapped and the value of the boolean `isChecked` changes, it updates in both the UI and in Firestore.

Now when I update my boolean's value, the change is reflected in real time in the UI as expected but when I attempt to make changes to the boolean from my UI, it's new value is not reflected in Firestore.

My diagnosis is that because `PlannerItemContainer` maintains its own state, my `StreamBuilder` isn't notified whenever a change is made.

My two questions are: 1.) Am I on the right track with my thinking and 2.) If I am is there a notifier function that I need to pass up from my `PlannerItemContainer` to the `StreamBuilder` that will notify it that there has been a change made to the `PlannerItemContainer` so that the realtime update is made to Firestore??

```
   StreamBuilder(
      stream: userProvider.watchHealthPlannerItems(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        plannerController.add(snapshot.data);

        return Timetable<HealthPlannerItem>(
          eventBuilder: (HealthPlannerItem item) {
            return Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: PlannerItemContainer(item),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

Stream passed to `StreamBuilder`:

```
 Stream<List<HealthPlannerItem>> watchHealthPlannerItems() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('organizations')
        .doc(this.organizationId)
        .collection('apps')
        .doc(this.appId)
        .collection('clients')
        .doc(this.user.id)
        .collection('healthplanner')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
        Map<String, dynamic> healthPlannerData = doc.data();
        HealthPlannerItem healthPlannerItem =
            HealthPlannerItem.fromJson(healthPlannerData);
        return healthPlannerItem;
      }).toList();
    });
  }
```

`PlannerItemContainer` widget:

```
class PlannerItemContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final HealthPlannerItem item;

  PlannerItemContainer(this.item);
  @override
  _PlannerItemContainerState createState() => _PlannerItemContainerState();
}

class _PlannerItemContainerState extends State<PlannerItemContainer> {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() => widget.item.isChecked = !widget.item.isChecked);
      },
      child: widget.item.isChecked
          ? _buildCheckedItemContainer(widget.item)
          : _buildUncheckedItemContainer(widget.item),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following everything completely but a quick scan shows me you're trying to change an immutable (final) variable "item" in your setState. you can move item into your state object and it can be mutable in there. Hopefully that gets you unstuck.